# Google AppEngine Yaml PHP Handler Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

Really simple setup; I just want to access any php file from the api folder (technically would like to specifiy `/api/.*` or something along that lines to include any subfolders) but this setup only returns 404; I have a feeling it is completely ignoring this line `- url: /api/app/(.+\.php)$` because if I type  asdfasdf.appspot.com/api/app/main.php (there is a `main.php` in the root directory) it loads. So this tells me it is staying in the root path the whole time. Any suggestions?

```
application: fsfhakjsldhf9
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

env_variables:
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/fudfsy9:us-central1:fuasdfe-prod1;dbname=f25dsfss9 
  MYSQL_USERNAME: fddadfs
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'asfdasdff'
  MYSQL_DATABASE: 'asdfasdf'

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /files
  static_dir: files

- url: /api/app/(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: main.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The `- url: /api/app/(.+\.php)$` also needed `script: /api/app/\1` to match